# Half circle motion between two matrices

Tags: python, math, matrix

I'm trying to move an object from point a to point b in an arc motion in 3D space. I've been reading up on matrices recently and am trying to get my head around them but to no avail. 
Let's say:

```
a = (x.100.0,y.200.0,z.300.0)
b = (x.-300.0,y.-100.0,z.0.0)
c = finding the middle of a,b matrices
d = start at a, do something with math.pi and multiplying the c matrices to give you and arc motion over to b.
```

Then calculate the arc position with c being at the middle of the arc. Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp I'm not sure that this is exactly what you want but it mapped exactly on how I parsed your question. If it is ok maybe I'll make it an answer as well.

Comment: There are infinitely many arcs between two points in 3D-space. Which one do you want?

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that link. And justhalf, that's a good point, I'm not sure how to word it but, it's the two points 'up' rotation vector is y lets say, it would move in and x,y arc. Similar to if it was 2d I spouse. I guess with the added dimension of 3d, position a would point towards position b and arc along the 'up' vector of both points. I hope that makes sense. At this stage, any arc will do if I'm honest, just struggling to work it out.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac , Slerp looks pretty interesting. I'm afraid I'm not sure how I would implement its formula or concept into my problem. Could you help me that if you have a moment?

Answer (score 1):

Let `u` and `v` be your two vectors. Normalize the two vectors to obtain `u'` and `v'`, respectively. Compute the cross product of `u'` and `v'` to get a vector `w` orthogonal to both of them.  Normalize `w` to obtain `w'`.

You now want to create a rotation `R` about axis `w'` such that `R * u' = v'`. As long as `u` and `v` are not colinear, there are only two options, corresponding to clockwise and counter-clockwise. One of these will be shorter, corresponding to the optimal rotation.

This section on Wikipedia describes how to construct `R`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

You have the axis `w'`, and the angle is `arccos(dot(u', v'))` because the dot product of unit vectors is the cosine of the angle between them.

Comment: You may know this so this is mainly for the OP's benefit: This will rotate one vector into another, but in general an orientation is described by a vector _and_ and angle (or a quaternion). If you are starting with rotation _matrices_ this answer is only half complete, if you want to rotate one vector into another or you have an axial symmetry this is fine.

Comment: @Hooked thank you for noting that. It makes sense now you've pointed it out. At this stage I would just be happy to get something working but I will need a solution to the problem you mentioned, when I won't have axial symmetry at somepoint.

Comment: @Timothy-Shields Thank you for your help, this sounds promising, I initially thought I may have to normalize the vectors but wasn't sure. How do I "create a rotation R about axis w' such that R * u' = v'"?

Comment: @justachap See update. If you're still confused, I think this might not be appropriate to continue on Stack Overflow...

Comment: @Timothy-Shields Thank you for that, and sorry to have wasted your time. The hardest thing to learn is the thing you haven't learnt yet, and not know what R stood for made it a little difficult to search for an explanation as  to what it was. But thank you any way...

Answer (score 0):

The center of your circle is M=(a+b)/2, its radius r= |a-b|/2 .  You find that point c when you go from  M in a direction perpendicular to (b-a):

```
c = M + r * v/abs(v)
```

with v being any vector perpendicular to (b-a).  One way to find such a perpendicular vector v is by taking the cross product of (b-a) with any arbitrary vector that's not parallel to (b-a), e.g.

```
v = (b-a) <crossproduct> (x.0, y.0, z.1)
```

As has been mentioned before there are many solutions to that problem, depending on v.